# Does Rust have a way to restrict string types to specific values (string literal types)?

Tags: rust

In Typescript, there are ways to type a value so it can have only be a specific string

e.g.

```
type example = "hello" | "world";
```

Am I limited to only the "String" type in rust or is there a way to narrow them down like there is in Typescript?

Right now I have:

```
pub struct ButtonProps {
    pub color: String
}
```

But color could be anything, I want it only to be "primary" or "secondary"

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent feature in Rust. We would simply use an `enum` in Rust to accomplish the same.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, ...)]
pub enum ButtonPropsColor { Hello, World }

pub struct ButtonProps {
  pub color: ButtonPropsColor,
}
```

Then, if you like, you can write conversion functions to get from `String` to `ButtonPropsColor` and vice versa.

```
impl From<&str> for ButtonPropsColor {
  fn from(s: &str) -> ButtonPropsColor {
    ...
  }
}

impl From<ButtonPropsColor> for String {
  fn from(s: ButtonPropsColor) -> String {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: And if you don't want to write those functions manually, the `strum` crate has macros for that